# Strange time zone in PostgreSQL timestamp conversion

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone-offset, timestamp-with-timezone, postgresql-9.6

This SQL:

```
select to_timestamp(extract(epoch from '0001-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp))
```

produces this output:

> 0001-01-01 08:06:00+08:06

I realize that `to_timestamp()` always adds a time zone, hence the additional 8 hours and `+8` in the time zone segment. But what is the `:06`? And where did the extra 6 minutes come from?

**EDIT**

If I initially execute `set local timezone to 'UTC';` then I get expected results.

Comment: and only for ancient date?.. what about 1812 year?..

Comment: Year 1812, same issue. +6 mins and 08:06 time zone.

Comment: This appears to happen on all dates pre 1900.

Comment: it's not conversion, try `select '1916-05-01 00:00:00'::timestamptz;` and `select '1916-08-01 00:00:00'::timestamptz;`

Comment: Those are fine. Conversion is from timestamp to epoch (seconds) and back.

Comment: If I initially execute `set local timezone to 'UTC';`, then I get expected results.

Comment: you run it in transaction?.. why local? and what is you session timezone?..

Comment: Running it in a PG Admin III query. I'm at Taipei +08.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before UTC was invented, each city had its own local time, mostly with a difference of just some minutes among each other.

Just after standardization of timezones (and the respective adoption by everybody), the local times were set to the values we know today.

That's why you get these strange results for ancient dates, specially before the year 1900.

Actually, Taipei changed from `UTC+08:06` to `UTC+08:00` only in [Jan 1<sup>st</sup> of 1896](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/taiwan/taipei?year=1850), so dates before it will have the `+08:06` offset.

If you set your timezone to UTC this doesn't happen, basically because UTC's offset is zero and never changes.

Comment: Wow! That's really interesting. Thank you.